# How to better implement WPF control cache?

Tags: c#, caching, collections, controls, garbage

My colleague discovered that we can often get a performance improvement in our WPF application if we cache WPF controls rather than new-ing them from scratch. Of course using more memory in general can cause a performance drop somewhere else that would be hard to measure, but we assumed that this would still be worth it because those controls take up insignificant amount of space compared to other things our app deals with.

Here is one simple form of a control cache:

```
public static class ControlCache<T> where T : Visual, new()
{
    private static Dictionary<T, bool> m_Cache = new Dictionary<T, bool>();

    public static T GetInstance()
    {
        if (m_Cache.Count == 0)
            return new T();
        else
        {
            var inst = m_Cache.First();
            m_Cache.Remove(inst.Key);
            return inst.Key;
        }
    }

    static int MAX_COUNT = 300;

    public static void Release(T ctrl)
    {
        if (ctrl != null && m_Cache.Count < MAX_COUNT && !m_Cache.ContainsKey(ctrl))
            m_Cache[ctrl] = true;
    }
}
```

One of the major draw backs of caching controls is the need to explicitly release them when you are done. Some times you really need to do something pretty awkward to make sure they are detached from their parent in just the right moment.
More importantly I feel it goes against the grain of the garbage collected environment.

What I am looking for is a strategy. How do I detect that a control (or an object) is not reachable and return it to my cache rather than making the consumer responsible for that?

I looked at using a Finilizer to bring the object back from the dead and back into the cache but this practice is generally considered bad for several good reasons. Also it does not exactly do what I'd like - it tells me when the object is about to be collected not when it becomes unreachable.

What is a good way?

Comment: If you want to know if the object has been finalized/garbage collected, you could store a weak reference to it and check the `IsAlive` property to determine if the reference has been garbage collected. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.weakreference(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Ron, I did look into WeakReferences  before I wrote the question. I did not mention them because they do not provide the solution for what I am asking. They do tell you if the object HAS BEEN garbage collected. There is also a way to get notified when it's about to be collected : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1145529/c-notification-before-weakreference-is-collected also a finalizer on the object will do that. What's missing is a way to bring it back safely and a way to be able to find out that it's unreachable right away (not when GC got to cleaning it).

Comment: I'm pretty sure that once all the references to an object are released and that object is ready to be GC'd, its out of your control to intercept and reclaim the object. As soon as an objects finalizer or `Dispose` method is run, that object must be considered unusable. Since you can't control when your cache user's call the finalizer or `Dispose`, you have to consider it gone as soon as you hand out the object.

Comment: Yep, this is why in my post I said "this practice is generally considered bad for several good reasons"... :)